# При использовании LiveData в Unit тестах вылетает NullPointerException

Tags: android, kotlin, исключения, junit, livedata

`gradle`:

```
android {

...

 sourceSets {
        test.java.srcDirs += 'src/test/java/com.sem.exchangerate'
        androidTest.java.srcDirs += 'src/androidTest/java/com.sem.exchangerate'
    }

    testOptions {
        execution 'ANDROIDX_TEST_ORCHESTRATOR'
        unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
    }

}

dependencies {

...

    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.9.0'
    implementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:4.7.0'
    implementation 'org.mockito.kotlin:mockito-kotlin:4.0.0'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.9.0'

    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.4.0'
    androidTestUtil 'androidx.test:orchestrator:1.4.1'

}
```

`Unit` тест:

```
class ExchangeRateUseCaseTest {

    val userRepository = mock<ExchangeRateCall>()

    @Test
    fun loadExchangeRate() {

        val testLiveData = listOf<ExchangeRateModel>(ExchangeRateModel(0, "name", 0.34), ExchangeRateModel(1, "name2", 0.35))

        val liveData = MutableLiveData<List<ExchangeRateModel>>()
        liveData.value = testLiveData // исключение возникает здесь
        Mockito.`when`(userRepository.loadCurrency()).thenReturn(liveData)

        val useCase = ExchangeRateUseCase(userRepository)
        val actual = useCase.loadExchangeRate()

        val liveData2 = MutableLiveData<List<ExchangeRateModel>>()
        liveData2.value = listOf<ExchangeRateModel>(ExchangeRateModel(0, "name", 0.34), ExchangeRateModel(1, "name2", 0.35))

        Assert.assertEquals(liveData2, actual)
    }
 }
```

класс `ExchangeRateUseCase`:

```
class ExchangeRateUseCase(private val exchangeRateCall : ExchangeRateCall) {

    fun loadExchangeRate(): LiveData<List<ExchangeRateModel>> {

        return exchangeRateCall.loadCurrency()

    }
    ...
 }
```

интерфейс `ExchangeRateCall`:

```
interface ExchangeRateCall {

    fun loadCurrency(): LiveData<List<ExchangeRateModel>>

...

}
```

исключение:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at androidx.arch.core.executor.DefaultTaskExecutor.isMainThread(DefaultTaskExecutor.java:77)
    at androidx.arch.core.executor.ArchTaskExecutor.isMainThread(ArchTaskExecutor.java:116)
    at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.assertMainThread(LiveData.java:486)
    at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.setValue(LiveData.java:306)
    at androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData.setValue(MutableLiveData.java:50)
    at com.sem.exchangerate.domain.useCase.ExchangeRateUseCaseTest.loadExchangeRate(ExchangeRateUseCaseTest.kt:21)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
...
```

исключение возникает в строке `liveData.value = testLiveData` Unit теста

Answer (score 0):

Как оказалось, нужно было добавить в тест:

```
  @Rule
    @JvmField
    val instantTaskExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()
```

чтобы получилось:

```
    @Rule
    @JvmField
    val instantTaskExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

    @Test
    fun loadExchangeRate() {

...

    }
```

и в gradle:

```
testImplementation 'androidx.arch.core:core-testing:2.1.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.arch.core:core-testing:2.1.0'
```